# Making a game that runs on Facebook and as a smart phone app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, html

I would like to know how one goes about designing an application that can be played on Facebook, as well as downloaded from the App Store as a standalone app, but allows games to be played between both platforms.
There are games out there like EA sports NFL social game. You can download the game and play others across multiple platforms, including Facebook.

What I do understand is that all the resources of the application are downloaded to the client device (unless playing through a browser, such as Facebook).
What I do not understand is how they have created a cross platform game using html for one platform, and an independent non-html sandbox application for another, and have both games interact as though they were one.

Also, Would I run a cgi script on my website that creates an executable program that handles the game logic to communicate between both models of the game?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan to create a 3D game you can think about using http://unity3d.com/ it allows you to play in Chrome and mobile devices. For mobile devices you can also use http://xamarin.com/.

You can also use canvas or webGL (not supported yet in mobile browsers but it will be soon) and for online gaming you can use HTML 5 web sockets.

About cross-platform online as you said you will need to handle it in the server side but it should not be a big deal, you just have multiple clients connected to one server...

Some frameworks you can explore are http://impactjs.com/ http://threejs.org/ http://www.createjs.com/

And if you feel brave in theory you can now convert any C++ game into javascript https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki